# Error while copy-pasting data from another ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to copy slide 1 from external ppt to current ppt into notes page. However, I'm getting this error msg:

> Slides (unknown member) : Invalid request. Clipboard is empty or
>   contains data which may not be pasted here.

The external ppt from where I'm copying does contains the data.

**VBA script:**

```
Sub copySlide()
Dim objPresentation As Presentation

Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("/path/slides.ppt")

objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Copy
Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste

objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't be this line : Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Paste that is wrong ? you want to paste your slide in the activePresentation?

Comment: Yes I want to copy the slide from an external ppt into currently open ppt through which I'm running the macros.

Comment: @RahulDagli see my answer below, let me know if it works as you intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below, I hope your presentation at `("/path/slides.ppt")` doesn't throw an error.

I added 2 options, either place it at the end, or as the second slide - you can modify the `Paste` line easily

**Code**

```
Sub copySlide()

Dim MyPres          As Presentation
Dim objPresentation As Presentation

Set MyPres = ActivePresentation
Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("/path/slides.ppt")

objPresentation.Slides(1).Copy
'MyPres.Slides.Paste MyPres.Slides.Count + 1 ' <-- place it at the end
MyPres.Slides.Paste 2 ' <-- place it as the second slide

objPresentation.Close
Set objPresentation = Nothing ' clear object

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code but I'm still getting error the same error on this line `MyPres.Slides.Paste 2 ' <-- place it as the second slide`

Comment: @RahulDagli there is a `'` in the code line, right ? between `MyPres.Slides.Paste 2` , and the comment afterwards ?

Comment: Yes I copied and pasted your code exactly, only the path I changed.

Comment: @RahulDagli what happens if you try the line before ? try using `'MyPres.Slides.Paste MyPres.Slides.Count + 1` see if it pastes to the end

Comment: @RahulDagli I'm not sure you are not failing copying the slide, what happens if you add `MsgBox objPresentation.Name & " has " & objPresentation.Slides.Count` afte the `Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open` line ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138199/discussion-between-rahul-dagli-and-shai-rado).

Comment: Solved! the trick is to first open the Normal view, run the macros then switch to notes view.